# form not redirecting to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

getStudents.js

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "displayStudents.php?branchCode=1",
    datatype:"JSON",
    success: function(obj){
        $("table").append("<form method='POST' action='markAttendance.php'>     <tr><th>Roll No</th>    <th>Name</th><th colspan='2'>Attendance</th></tr>");
        for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
            $("table").append(
                "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i].RollNo+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i].Name+"</td>"+
                "<td><input type='radio' name='mark["+i+"]' value='Present'>Present" +
                "<input type='radio' name='mark["+i+"]' value='Absent' checked>Absent</td>" +
                "</tr>"
                );
        }
        $("table").append("<tr><td><button type='submit' name='submitMark' id='submitMark'>Mark Attendance</button></td></tr></form>");
        $("#submit").hide();
    }    
})
});
```

In the html file there is a table and button having id as submit. I am getting the json correctly and it is also displayed properly. But whenever I click on the Mark Attendance Button, it is not redirected to markAttendance.php.

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: It will not go to markattendence Page as Form only get submitted on submit button but mark attendence is not of type submit

Comment: @mvermand There is no error. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh. It is of type submit. What are you saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your call  like this:

```
$('body').on('click',"#submit",function(){
```

As it's AJAX, page is not going to redirect on displayStudents.php. There will be an async call to the page.

You can track on inspect tools --> network tab.

Instead of `<table><form></form></table>` structure, do `<form><table></table></form>`

Comment: The method didn't work. And thanks for the async call part.

Comment: check you console logs.. there may be any error that can help u rectify

Comment: Yes, the displayStudents.php

Comment: if it showing then it means your function is calling. then whats the issue..? are you able to get response of XHR ?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the response as JSON data.

Comment: ohh yes.. just consider your table inside a form tag instead of form in table.